# How to add custom header with <String, Integer> to Spring Boot HttpHeaders?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Currently Spring Boot HttpHeaders header only takes `<String, String>` pairs. How can I add a header with  `<String, Long>`?

I need to integrate with one of the external product API in my Java Program, to access this API, it needs a token header which for this product, all of its APIs only takes Numbers(long). It is so out of ordinary and it gives me a lot headache. I am using RestTemplate and I've searched a lot place with no luck.

Did any of you have done anything similar to this? Need some help.

Comment: Headers are transmitted as text strings across the network. Just convert your number to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create generic header using [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) that accepts `String` as key and `Object` as value

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("Header1", 11111);
```

And then create generic [HttpEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) of object type by passing `MultiValueMap` as headers

```
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map);

System.out.println(entity);
```

Comment: It kind works for get. But what about post? I can't really create entity with body. It requires (string, string) for header

Comment: Can you show the code, without seeing your code i can't say how to refactor it @gamewu

Comment: use `exchange` method for both `GET` and `POST` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference- @gamewu